# How to show my own design button in a QCommandLinkButton

Tags: qt

I'm trying to make an UI with that kind of buttons. I make a kinda design for my buttons and I want to make all my buttons look like that. The only way, for now, I have found to do that is load my design in the icon of my buttons and set its size the same as the button. It works...but not perfectly...my image is not in the center of the button...as you can see

[image: example of m button]

the blue is my own design and the gray that looks up is the real button. So my problem is I can't center my design on the button. I tried to look for options but I didn't find any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [Qt Stylesheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) for this type of thing. Check out the [examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html), they show simple button styles there.

Comment: So I should try to do the same design that I did by using Stylesheets?!?!

Comment: Yes, that's what they are for.

Comment: finally I use the StyleSheets to make the button kind of invisible so my icon is now perfectly visible and not the button. Thanks for the StyleSheet clue

Comment: That's a nice trick :-) Not what I had in mind, but good if that works for you!

Comment: Haha thanks. That exacly when I read the doc you gave me that I had the idea, when I saw : `background:none` :P

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can use stylesheets. Try using `QToolButton` instead of `QPushButton`. `QToolButton` has several options for making a button more visually appealing, For ex:things like you said are more easily doable using QToolButton. It has some built-in features like popup-mode and toolbuttonstyle[which accomplishes your task] ready-made available to say the least.